# Android cursor.moveBeforeFirst()

Tags: java, android, cursor

Why does `Cursor` have no `moveBeforeFirst()` in Android?

There are similar methods in other flavours of Java, and they are useful if you need to re-iterate over a resultset (for example, in a `while(cursor.moveToNext()) {...}` loop).

Currently, I am achieving the desired effect by using `cursor.moveToPosition(-1)`, but given the lack of a `moveBeforeFirst()` method, I am wondering if this is good practice? (Whereas I think my only alternative would be to re-run the same query...)

Comment: There is a moveToFirst() method...

Comment: `moveBeforeFirst` will go to `last row` ?? if so we have `moveToLastRow` :-/

Comment: @brso05 `moveToFirst()` method move to first position of the cursor so when you want to iterate it using `while(cursor.moveToNext())` loop it will acctualy start from second element not first, this is why @ban-geoengineering needs to set cursor before first position

Comment: I know what it does but you can change your loop to a do while loop or there are many options to change your loop so it will work.

Comment: @ban-geoengineering you should just use absolute position like you are.  cursor.moveToPosition(-1);

Comment: Cheers. So why does Cursor have no moveBeforeFirst() in Android??

Comment: "Why" questions like this are not really answerable. We don't have time machines and mind reading capabilities. We can speculate but that's not really suited for SO ("primarily opinion based"). My speculative answer to the why: there was no need for such method as cursor (re)iteration can be achieved with the canonical moveToFirst - do{} while(moveToNext) method.

Comment: I don't think that's a fair comment. If there's an unusual omission in the API then there's a good chance someone knows why - not because they have built a time machine or are telepathic, but because they may be more clued up than me in the workings/limitations of SQLite / Android and can provide an answer based on their superior knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

try in this way, use do while loop, it give you all list include first and last row.

```
    if (cursor != null) {  
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do{

            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        } else {
           //cursor empty
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would achieve the desired behaviour as following

```
if (myCursor != null) { //Tests to see if the cursor exists. 
    if (myCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        // myCursor moved to the first record
    } else {
        // myCursor is empty
    }
} else {
    // myCursor is null
}
```

Calling moveToFirst() does two things: it allows you to test whether the query returned an empty set (by testing the return value) and it moves the cursor to the first result (when the set is not empty).

Comment: Can you update your answer with how this would work with a loop, because if I use `myCursor.moveToFirst()` before `while(myCursor.moveToNext()) {...}` then the first row will be skipped.